# How to return a string of a number with 1 decimal and others without the decimal place?

Tags: javascript

In JS, I want to output a string with 1 decimal place for particular values whilst others will be whole numbers (e.g. `999999 = "999.9k"`, `500000 = "500k"` and `1000000 = 1M`). Instead, I'm getting: `999999 = "1000.0k"`, `500000 = "500.0k"` and `1000000 = 1.0M`

This is what I've tried:

```
function formatLargeNumber(n) {
  let s = "";
  if (n < 1000) {
    s += n;
  } else if (n >= 1000 && n < 1000000) {
    s += (Math.round(n)/1000).toFixed(1) + "k"
  } else if (n >= 1000000) {
    s += (Math.round(n)/1000000).toFixed(1) + "M"
  } 
  return s
};
```

I've attempted to use `Math.trunc` but it outputs values such `499999` to equal `499.999k`

I could convert the result to string first, split it by '.' character and add some if else statement whether or not I want to display the decimal place but I'm unsure how to write this out.

Comment: Use `toFixed()` or `toFixed(0)`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/number/tofixed

Comment: @JayBuckman this seems to round up the numbers which I don't want

Comment: Whether or not you should quote figures to different degrees of precision if they happen to be multiples of 10 is a matter for debate.  But if you do want to do that, then you'll need conditional code to deal with those special cases: for example, you could look at the string, and remove the trailing ".0" (before adding the suffix).

Comment: Well if you don't want the decimal then don't use `.toFixed(1)` but `.toFixed(0)` - am I missing something?

Comment: Btw, you probably don't want to round twice. Don't use `Math.round` if `toFixed` already does the rounding.

Comment: I was thinking of converting the result to string first, split it by '.' character and add some if else statement whether or not I want to display the decimal place

Comment: For removing the decimals you can use something like `.replace(/\.0$/,'')` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I found in https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/convert-file-size-bytes-kb-mb-gb-javascript/

```js
// from https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/convert-file-size-bytes-kb-mb-gb-javascript/
function formatFileSize(bytes,decimalPoint) {
   if(bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
   var k = 1000,
       dm = decimalPoint || 2,
       sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
       i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
   return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}

[123,3347,2234556,12345342355,123423444332,234.5678e15].forEach(n=>console.log(formatFileSize(n,1)))
```

A customised version of the script that will *truncate* the decimal digits (instead of *rounding* the number) after a given length could look like this:

```js
// from https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/convert-file-size-bytes-kb-mb-gb-javascript/
function formatFileSize(bytes,decimalPoint) {
   if(bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
   var k = 1000,
       dm = decimalPoint || 2,
       sizes = ['', ' k', ' m', ' g', ' t', ' p', ' e', ' z', ' y'],
       i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
   return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i))).toFixed(8).slice(0,dm-8).replace(/\.0*$/,"") + sizes[i];
}

[123,3347,2234556,12993453455,123063444332,234.5678e15].forEach(n=>console.log(formatFileSize(n,1)))
```

Having utilised the above mentioned solution to produce a snippet satisfying OP' s requirements I would like to point out that the way it calculates the quantities is not compliant to the actual definition of storage size units (see [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-file-sizes-bytes-kb-mb-gb-tb-pb-eb-zb-yb/amp/)). The factor between the units should actually be 1024 (2^10) instead of 1000 (10^3).

Comment: This is effective by changing sizes to `['', 'k', 'M']` but values such as 999, 9999 etc are rounded and 999,999 = 1000k

Comment: ... which is what you would expect from rounding. The reputation score here in SO is shown in a similar way.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to alter it to match the result which I need. The code works really well but values <1000 have a decimal point. I'll see how I can change the code to resolve this.